# Are there any equivalent DataObject.AddPastingHandler in WinRT, Win8?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, copy-paste

I want to handling Copy-Paste event so should use AddPastingHandler.

Are there any equivalent DataObject.AddPastingHandler in WinRT, Win8?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The namespace to start looking for Windows Store apps is `Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer` which is [described in MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.aspx).

Comment: @RogerRownland
thanks for your answer but I didn't see equivalent event in DataPackage. Could you explain it to me, please?

Comment: @TuğrulEmreAtalay well it's a big subject because the whole concept of sharing is different in Windows Store Apps. Your question was very broad, so I gave an equally broad answer. Are you implementing sharing between apps or just clipboard operations? Why not update your question to make it more specific what you want to do and show your source code so far?

Comment: @RogerRownland okey, so it's what I want :
I have a customized Textbox like PasswordBox and I want to block Copy-Paste events in it. How can I disable it?

Comment: @TuğrulEmreAtalay ok, I see you already asked that question, were none of the answers or comments helpful?

Comment: I had not see any event that provides handling pasting yet.

Comment: @TuğrulEmreAtalay then there probably isn't one. As I said above, the concepts are quite different and a lot of functionality is wrapped in the available controls. As commenters on your other question have said, you will probably have to implement your own custom text box.

Comment: @RogerRownland I got it. So could you explain it to me, how can I handle this event in my custom text box? I am also using my custom textbox.

Comment: @TuğrulEmreAtalay I'm just guessing here but what I would do is to trap the event when the control gets focus and then clear the clipboard. So even if the user had copied something, they can't paste it into your control.

Comment: @RogerRownland Thank you but my bosses dont allow me to clearing clipboard :(

Comment: @TuğrulEmreAtalay maybe you can copy any clipboard text locally when you get focus and then clear the clipboard. When you lose focus, put the text back on the clipboard. That way the user can't paste and the clipboard stays healthy for any other apps.

Comment: Yes, that is so cleverly. Thank you Roger :)